# AES encryptor mangles only first part of input data using initialization vector

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

Consider the following code (you also may check in [sandbox](https://onlinegdb.com/7R5omu5WJg)):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class EncryptionIVTest
{
    private static readonly string Data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    private static readonly byte[] Password = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray().Take(32).ToArray();

    static void Main()
    {
        var iv = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray().Take(16).ToArray(); // random initialization vector
        var iv2 = new byte[16]; // just another zero-filled initialization vector
        var encrypted = Encrypt(iv);

        Console.WriteLine($"Original: {Data}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted: {encrypted}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Decrypted: {Decrypt(encrypted, iv)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Decrypted with another IV: {Decrypt(encrypted, iv2)}"); // It should throw exception or output completely mangled string
    }

    private static string Encrypt(byte[] iv)
    {
        var cipher = CreateCipher(iv);
        var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new CryptoStream(ms, cipher.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }

    private static string Decrypt(string encrypted, byte[] iv)
    {
        var cipher = CreateCipher(iv);
        using var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted));
        using var result = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new CryptoStream(ms, cipher.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            stream.CopyTo(result);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)result.Length);
    }

    private static Aes CreateCipher(byte[] iv)
    {
        var cipher = Aes.Create();
        cipher.Key = Password;
        cipher.IV = iv;
        cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        return cipher;
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```cs
Original: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Encrypted: EROKh8lVgREvTqzBYXjEm7EbTIT883uR9wsD82lRM14KtiOYr+/+ZpAwz/UfprqSP5mIQ7Du/d43Y88hAPjvkA==
Decrypted: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Decrypted with another IV: ???@?n? ??7║??Paaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The fourth string is not fully mangled, it contains an untouched trailing. It seems like encryptor only mangle first 16 bytes (size of an initialization vector) and leaves other untouched. By default, encryptor uses [`CBC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode?view=net-5.0) CipherMode and it should mangle all data if I understand correctly.

Is it possible to mangle all data, not only the first part?

Comment: In addition to my answer -- did you try a second RANDOM IV instead of an empty one? I'm curious if the output would be complete garbage. I suspect it would.

Comment: But you didn't encrypt it twice, each with a different IV. Instead you tried decrypting it with the correct key but different IVs. This is as expected, see the discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC))

Comment: @PeterMoore, yes, I tried, but it does not change anything: output is only partly garbage.

Comment: Ok. Well like I said it's not a concern. As long as using the wrong KEY produces fully mangled output - and encrypting using different IVs produces completely different output - you're fine. The attacker cannot guess the key, that's what matters. But don't forget to use the right .net apis to make your keys!!!

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the IV is not to "mangle" data further or to serve as a second encryption key - that would just make it redundant of the actual key.

The purpose is to provide additional entropy so that two sets of plaintext data encrypted with the same key but with different IVs will appear completely different when encrypted. This makes it harder for an attacker to infer anything about the data. For example, without the IV, sophisticated attackers could run statistical analyses based on language patterns and potentially figure out what certain encrypted packets actually are based on how frequently they occur.

So what you're seeing should not be surprising or concerning. The IV is doing its job.

By the way, using a Guid as a key is NOT secure. First of all it's only 16-bytes not 32 so you only have a 128-bit key basically. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/generating-keys-for-encryption-and-decryption#symmetric-keys for the right apis to use to generate keys and IVs